# Coded UI customize the code generated after recording

Tags: coded-ui-tests

The coded ui recorder saves controls to the UIMap. What I am looking for is a way to customize the output and also fire up a wizard process after save, that can generate code in other places in my project.

The best approach I could find so far (But it's a long winded and complex process) is this:

1. Write either a windows service / visual studio plugin / console app (that should be running) -> inside here hookup a directory watch class to check for changes to UIMap file.
2. Using DiffPlex - grab the changes to the UIMap.
3. Using string manipulation grab the Id and FriendlyName of the XML elements changed
4. Using XPath locate the element and traverse upwards to root, giving us the OOP lookup chain for example UIMap.MainForm.LayoutControl.CustomersGrid
5. Throw up my custom form and ask user for input -> based on this generate code in my project at the right places

I wish there was a plugin model to be able to customize the code generation. This or if Coded UI Recorder was open source would be able to customize the code.

Is my approach the only way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain the reason you're doing it this way? Since the recorder is locked up it's hard to do it easier than you've got it now, but there might be other options more suitable for your problem.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/10/coded-ui-test-configuring-search-properties-while-recording-on-internet-explorer.aspx and also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269473(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Thomas, I did investigate the above but I hit so many issues. Instead I have opted for copying control reference to clipboard and then generating code from that, since this has the element lookup path, it's pretty much all I will need from the UIMap.

Comment: We're currently working without an UIMap, not with the automation like you want but I'm sure it's easy enough to build since you're doing the search in the code. [This](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/03/build-a-coded-ui-test-without-a-ui-map/) blogpost helped a lot.